# Existence of transverse null vector bundle in a degenerate Lorentzian hypersurface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry, lorentzian-geometry

*This question is cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3234895/existence-of-transverse-null-vector-bundle*

Let $(M,g)$ be a Lorentzian manifold. Let $\dim(M)=d$. Given a null hypersurface, i.e., a smooth embedding $(H, \phi )$ of $M$ s.t. $\dim(H)=d-1$, $h:= \phi ^* g$ over $H$ is degenerate with $rank(h_p)=d-2$ at each $p \in H$. Let $\phi^*(TM)$ be the induced bundle of $M$ over $H$.

Define the degenerate subspace as $C_p H=\{X_p\in T_p H : h(X_p,Y_p) =0, \forall Y_p\in T_pH\}$, and the corresponding $CH= \sqcup_{p\in H} C_p H$. It can be shown that this defines a vertical subbundle of $TH$. Consider the complementary bundle of $\phi'(TH)$ in the induced bundle $\phi ^*(TM)$, as say $RH$. There is an arbitrary choice of such an $RH$; they are all isomorphic to the normal bundle say $NH$, but the choice is by no means unique.

Now the question is about the existence of some specific kind of $RH$. **Does there exist a choice of $RH$ s.t. $CH\oplus RH$ is non-degenerate with respect to the metric $g$ induced over it? Further, can you make such a choice with the additional constraint that $RH$ is itself degenerate w.r.t $g$ induced over it? ([1] for details).** I need the existence; the uniqueness I'm sure does not hold.

[1] By $g$ induced over a vertical subbundle $E$ of $\phi^*(TM)$, I mean the following: let $\iota:E \rightarrow \phi^*(TM) $ denote the embedding map. Now, it is known that the map $\phi' :TH \rightarrow TM$ splits into a vertical and horizontal part over $\phi^*(TM)$. Use the horizontal part $\phi'_h:\phi^*(TM) \rightarrow TM$, to induce a metric on $E$ as $\iota^*(\phi_v^*g)$. It is with respect to such induced metric that I say that $RH\oplus CH$ should be non-degenerate, and $RH$ should be degenerate.

**Addendum**. The corresponding statement on the level of linear subspaces is true, and I know how to do that. It's at the level of bundles that it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $CH$ is [complemented](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/direct+sum+of+vector+bundles#TopologicalSubBundlesOverParacompactHausdorffSpacesAreDirectSummands) in $TH = CH \oplus SH$, with $SH$ some non-unique choice of complementary sub-bundle. Then the restricted metric on $SH$ is non-degenerate (of Riemannian signature). The orthogonal complement $S^\perp H$ in $\phi^*(TM)$ is a rank-2 bundle and the restricted metric on it is Lorentzian. The null cone of a rank-2 Lorentzian metric is the union of two null lines. Obviously, globally the null cone bundle of $S^\perp H$ then decomposes into the union of two null vector sub-bundles of $S^\perp H$, with $CH$ being one of them (by construction), while you can take the other one to be the desired $RH$.

Comment: Just a little clarification: When you say a rank-2 Lorentzian bundle is the union of two null bundles, you mean that- since at the linear level: for dim=2 lorentzian vector spaces, there are precisely 2 null vectors, it make it possible to uniquely construct the lorentzian bundle as the direct sum of two null bundles. Right?

Comment: I meant 2 unique null subspaces, not just 2 null vectors.

Comment: @SandeshJr, please note that I wrote "**null cone bundle** of $S^\perp H$ then decomposes into the union of two null vector sub-bundles". But then, the direct sum of these sub-bunldles obviously spans $S^\perp H$, as you remarked explicitly (and I implicitly).

Comment: I see. Great answer; thanks!